# Find conditional expectation given symmetric r.v

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

How to find $E[sin(X)|cos(X)]$, if X - a symmetric random variable?

My attempt: I tried to prove that $sin(X)$ is $\sigma(cos(X))$-measurable. Then it can be argued that $E[sin(X)|cos(X)]=sin(X)$. But in this case, symmetry is not used.

I am completely sure that this is the wrong answer.

Comment: If you know cos(x), what are the possible values for sin(x)?

Comment: @assumednormal yes: $+-\sqrt{1-cos^2X}$

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4264206/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: ok and what?